# ANOVA with repeated mesures - No random groups

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have 4 groups, 3 of them receiving a treatment and the last nothing. I will do two mesures, before and after the treatment. But my groups are pre-defined, not resulting of a random selection.

Is it nonetheless valid to use an ANOVA with repeated mesures ?

Thank's beforehand

Answer (score 2):

You have two factors:

- "Group" (Treatment or control, so four treatment groups)
- Time (before and after the treatment).

So two-way ANOVA with repeated measures in one factor would be an appropriate analysis.

Interpretation of almost any statistical result is based on the idea assumption that your sample data were sampled from infinite populations or the more practical assumption that your data are representative of a larger population you want to generalize about. You say "groups are predefined" but that is too vague to help decide if statistical results will be helpful.